# Avoiding circular dependencies with Node require()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, electron, circular-dependency

I'm having a problem where I have an Electron app, we'll say contained in files `index.html` and `app.js`. `app.js` is included in `index.html` with a script tag.

Within `app.js`, I use `var ENGINE = require("./myGameEngine/");` which then requires different classes, each in their own file. It looks something like this:

```
var myEngine = myEngine || {};
myEngine.ClassA = require('./src/ClassA');
myEngine.ClassB = require('./src/ClassB');
myEngine.ClassC = require('./src/ClassC');
module.exports = myEngine;
```

Unfortunately, sometimes `ClassA`, needs to use `new myEngine.ClassB()`. For example, if `ClassA` is an entity and has the function `ClassA.addComponent()` that function might require the use of `var component = new myEngine.ClassB()`.

When trying to do this, I run into an error that `myEngine` is undefined, even though it's the parent that required all these other files. I don't want to require it back in `ClassB` as that will create a circular dependency, but I *need* `ClassB` inside `ClassA` sometimes.

What's most infuriating is that previously, instead of including `app.js` with script tags and requiring `myEngine` with `require()` I simply required both `myEngine.js` and `app.js` from the HTML file, and that all worked fine.

I could go back to that system but I liked the simplicity of including a single JS file to go with my single HTML file, and doing all the requiring of the game engine inside that JS file, alongside modules from node_modules.

Can someone explain to me how what the problem is here and how I can require files within a module, without having to redefine the module in every file?

Thank you in advance!

**Edit 1:** Regarding suggestions to include the classes within other classes, I have created a drawing about why I'd like to avoid that: [Can of Worms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njxGN.jpg)

**Edit 2:** Although I could require every class in every other class, there is is the issue of needing to access the parent module's variables (that's the main issue that caused me to write this, since I didn't want to require the parent in the child and the child in the parent).

To be specific about that, consider this case:

```
myEngine.Entity = require('./src/Entity.js');
myEngine.Component = require('./src/Component.js');
myEngine.System = require('./src/System.js');
```

`System.js` has a method called `update()` which looks roughly like:

```
update: function(){
  for (let i = 0; i < myEngine.entities.length; i++) {
    doSomeLogic( myEngine.entities[i] );
  }
}
```

This did work when I used the script tags to include myEngine in the app, and no longer works when I include myEngine as a Node module. That's sort of the crux of my frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer for myself.

By using `myEngine = module.parent.exports` in my sub classes, I can access not only the other classes (as long as the class doesn't use the sub class until after the other class has been included in the parent's `module.exports`), but also access higher scope variables like `myEngine.entities`.

Answer (score 0):

How about `require`ing ClassB directly from ClassA, rather than going through the parent module.

So in `ClassA` just `require('./classB')`

Comment: Well the short answer is it feels ugly to me to require everything in everything else. Would honestly be cleaner at that point to 

The long answer is that that would cause issues with ever calling one of those functions in a different scope though because it would be relying on whatever the sub-module was called when it was required in that file, instead of what it was called "globally" (even if this is not a true global).

Also, still doesn't explain why it used to work when the game engine was included in a script tag instead of required in `app.js`.

Comment: require is a nodejs function. Unless you are using a build tool (browserify, webpack, e.g.) to compile the modularized code for the browser's consumption, the browser is not going to understand what require means. That could explain why it worked when added to the global scope via a script tag, but not when required from app.js.

Comment: I don't see how it's an issue of the browser not understanding the require() function... I do get that the script tag put it in the global scope.

Can you recommend a solution for this other than requiring module by module within modules? I've done a little illustration of why I'd like to avoid that. [Can of Worms](http://i.imgur.com/ymbxXm1.jpg)

I have searched for something like web worker's ability to simply include some external code at a point within the file. I can't find anything other than `require()` though.

Comment: As far a module structuring goes, I would move the shared parts between the two classes into into its own class D, require D from app, and then require A and B from D. The problem remains though that require will not work in the browser without first being compiled. require is not a native js function, it is a nodejs function. The browser does not run nodejs, just pure js. Try using a tool called browserify to compile the modulized code into js the browser can understand.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I'm not trying to be difficult but that's really not a solution. In this case B *is* a sort of D which other places require, but the issue is that it also needs to be accessed by the main parent file of the module and potentially the user.

Is the solution then just to require D in multiple places? Feels messy and hacky but maybe it's the only answer.

Also, this is an Electron app, so Node code does work and that's why I did not look into Webpack, Browserify, or something like that.

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't see anything wrong with requiring the shared module, D, in multiple places.

Comment: There's also the issue of a certain class needing to access the parent module's array of all entity instances to do work on them. I can't require the parent with its array to do work on it because the array at time of require is empty.

In any case, I've been really frustrated and roadblocked by this... I might just go back to including the engine in a script tag because that worked. It felt like it shouldn't be necessary but it's a hell of a lot cleaner than requiring everything in everything else. :(

Comment: Updated original question with more details about why I would not simply require each class in each other class (see Edit 2).

Comment: One strategy you might try is dependency injection. If you want to access the parent array from the child, how about just passing it down at call time.

Comment: Yeah I might, although it also feels redundant and messy to add more mandatory arguments to a function which have only 1 acceptable value. Anyway, thank you for your help; I'm starting to feel like the problem is me, and I'm trying to not find a solution picking everything apart.

Also sorry this isn't a chat: SO suggested I move it to a chat and then said I didn't have enough reputation. Thanks for the tip, SO.